# How to mimic watermark in excel using softartisans ExcelWriter? If so do we have any sample code for it?

Tags: officewriter

Sample Code:

```
ExcelApplication xla = new ExcelApplication();
Workbook wb = xla.Create();
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];
Shapes shps = ws.Shapes;
Anchor anch = ws.CreateAnchor(0, 7, 0, 0);
Shape shpHeart = shps.CreateShape(ShapeType.TextBox, anch);
shpHeart.FillTransparency=0.5;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Does the sample code above not work?  It looks like it should.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Excel doesn't have the concept of a watermark.  The problem with adding a shape or image to a worksheet is that it will float over the cells.  If you want something to appear behind the cells, the best way is to put a large image in the header or footer, as described in this MS article: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/mimic-a-watermark-in-excel-HP010103239.aspx

To do this programmatically with the ExcelWriter API, you can use the [SetContent method](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/HeaderFooterSection.SetContent%28String,+System.IO.Stream%29) of the [HeaderFooterSection object](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/HeaderFooterSection). You can also adjust dimensions of the image with the [HeaderFooterPicture object](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/HeaderFooterPicture).

Example:

```
ExcelApplication xla = new ExcelApplication();
Workbook wb = xla.Create(ExcelApplication.FileFormat.Xlsx);
Worksheet sheet1 = wb.Worksheets[0];
PageSetup pgsetup = sheet1.PageSetup;
HeaderFooterSection centerFooter = pgsetup.GetFooter(HeaderFooterSection.Section.Center);
string watermarkImagePath = @"C:\images\watermark.jpg";
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(watermarkImagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {    
        //Note: Excel requires including the "&G" code when inserting 
        //an image in a header or footer
        centerFooter.SetContent("&G",fs);
    }
xla.Save(wb, Page.Response, "watermarktest.xlsx", false);
```

More information about formatting headers and footers: http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Formatting+Headers+and+Footers